# what is the meaning of もので in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

what is the meaning of もので in the following sentence?

> ウンジさんは友達と一緒に山登りに参加したいと思っている。バスを使わずに最初から歩いて登れる**もので**、土曜日のコースがいい。ウンジさんたちの希望に合うのはどれか

if I use  ことで to replace もので、will the meaning of sentence be the same?

Answer (score 1):

That もの refers to （山登りの）コース like the English pronoun "one" would. They prefer *one that allows them to hike from the start without riding the bus and that is open on Saturdays.*

もの appearing before コース might have confused you. You can rephrase the sentence to:

> バスを使わずに最初から歩いて登れるコースで、土曜日のものがいい。

The original sentence sounds better to me not because of the word order per se but because 土曜日のもの sounds a bit awkward.

Because this もの refers to a concrete thing (like "one" would), it can't be replaced with こと.

Comment: thank you,but you have a source for this usage? I want to learn the usage in detail

Comment: @CN.hitori - This is a pretty standard usage of もの. It basically means "thing". Any dictionary should do. It is used here instead of repeating コース twice.

Comment: @CN.hitori - の also works here, except it would make the sentence ambiguous because it could be seen as part  of 〜ので indicating reason (for preferring one on a Saturday).